# Firebase database is giving inconsistent DataSnapshot when listening on multiple paths in the same time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We had a crash in our Android app and it was really hard to debug. Finally we cracked it:

- in our app, we are listening on these two paths in the same time: `groups/$id` and `groups/$id/name`
- we create a new `Group` object through the REST API which includes `name` parameter
- first a ValueEventListener is triggered with a DataSnapshot of the group object but WITHOUT a `name`. That was invalid state in our app which caused the crash.
- second a ValueEventListener is triggered for the name only with a correct value

We fixed it by listening only on the group object, not on both. But it's really confusing and not documented. Is this an expected behavior? Can we do it better?

Comment: The Firebase Database never sends partial nodes. If you get the group without its name, it is very likely you have code that writes the group without its name. Is there any way you can reproduce this in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?